# Purposeful lag between camera to hdtv with hdmi

Tags: tethering, live-view

Is there a way I can purposefully increase the time between when my camera (Sony HDR-PJ10) sees something and when my tv displays it using HDMI?

Comment: In the olden analog days, tv broadcasters had kilometers of cables lying around to provide literal delay loops.

Comment: Get some HDMI capture hardware for your computer, then find a software DVR that's compatible with that video source, and pause it for *n* seconds so that playback lags behind "live".

Answer (score 1):

All that is happening when you use the HDMI feed is that a lot of data is being sent down a cable to represent each frame of video.

To delay that video data requires a device that can buffer a lot of data and then send it out later.

That would require some kind of video input device that can accept the HDMI and has some kind of large reasonably fast storage , so that's some kind of computer with a video capture capability.

Basically it's recording video and then replaying it later.  You might find a set-top box that can do it, but I don't know of one off the top of my head.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate on why you think that.

Comment: i remember some tv set advertisement that was focused on such feature (pause and resume live broadcast. the "live" broadcast is then delayed)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much a matter of cost and how much delay you want.  You might want to look at relatively inexpensive delay boxes like this [Roland](http://www.markertek.com/Attachments/Specifications/RolandProfessional/VC-1-DL-Specifications.pdf) unit, which can delay up to 4.5 frames.  A quick scan around advertisements suggests that the cost for a full buffer-and-send box capable of long delays is in the many thousands.

Comment: Please forgive me for my ignorance, why one want such a delay?

Comment: @user152435 They're used in broadcasting to help sync audio and video, so that the speech of a person on camera matches the movement of their lips. I'm sure you've seen cases where the audio wasn't properly synced, and it just looks ridiculous when it's even a little bit off. Longer delays have other uses, like creating a 7-second delay for bleeping forbidden words, etc. I don't know for certain, but I suspect sports broadcasts sometimes delay the video a little more than the audio so that the commentators are  able to explain things almost as they happen.